# How to compute the integrate of kernel density function power to a?

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to compute the following integration in R:

[image]

where

[image]

denotes the kernel density function and kernel estimation of the cumulative distribution function and the bandwidth is chosen as follows:

[image]

I want to generate from beta(x,2,2) and compute the above estimator. I wrote the following codes

```
fh<-function(n,x){
z<-rbeta(n,2,2)
sigma<-min(sd(z),(quantile(z,0.75)-quantile(z,0.25))/1.34)
h<-(1.06)*n^(-1/5)*sigma
sum<-0
for(i in 1:n){
 sum<-sum+(1/(n*h))*dnorm((x-z[i])/h)
    }
return(sum)
}

Fh<-function(n,x){
z<-rbeta(n,2,1)
sigma<-min(sd(z),(quantile(z,0.75)-quantile(z,0.25))/1.34)
h<-(1.06)*n^(-1/5)*sigma
sum<-0
for(i in 1:n){
 sum<-sum+pnorm((x-z[i])/h)
    }
return(sum/n)
}

fhat_kn<-function(n,x,t){
(-log(Fh(n,x)/Fh(n,t)))^(n-1)*(fh(n,x)/Fh(n,t))
}

Hhatkn<-function(n,t,a){
integrate(function(x) (fhat_kn(k,n,x))^a,lower=0,upper=t)$value
}

I just want to compute the above function for data generated from beta(2,2). Could you please someone help me?
```

Comment: Thank you for updating your previous question.  The formatting here is much better!  However, my secondary question is still valid.  Since the beta distribution is usually regarded as a two parameter distribution, your statements "I want to generate from beta(x,2,2)" and "I want to compute the bias and mse where X\~beta(2,,2)" are unclear.

Comment: In fact, by generating a random sample for example n=50 from beta distribution with parameters 2 and 2, I want to compute the g_a(t) for instance a=0.5 and t=2. I hope this will be clear. Please note that in the bandwidth h, that sigma is estimated by min{S, Q/1.34} in which S is the sample standard deviation and  Q=Q_3-Q_1 is the interquartile range.